# Cannot find displacement in material panel - blender 2.83

Tags: texturing, displacement

I cannot find "displacement" in the material panel anymore in blender 2.83. I want to change my displacement type from "bump only" to "displacement and bump" but I cannot right now. When I opened my old files i can see the displacement there but not in my new file. Is that a bug or do I did something wrong?
Thanks

[The new file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUL6v.png)
[The old file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvLHi.png)

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your Render engine, that option is only for Cycles
Go to Render Properties > Render Engine

Comment: omg yes this absolutely solve the problem thanks so much!